# CommandLink with parameter in actionListener method doesn't work inside f:facet of datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-2.2

I'd like to be able to click the headers in a table to sort the respective columns. When I try to do this with a `h:commandLink` and pass the column name as a parameter I get an error saying that the commandLink needs to be ended with `>` or `/>`, which I do. Example:

```
<h:column>
   <f:facet name="header">
       <h:commandLink
           value="name"
           actionListener="#{albumListBean.sort("album_name")}">
       </h:commandLink>
   </f:facet>
   <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" styleClass="tableItem" />
</h:column>
```

I get the same result using `f:ajax` or p:commandLink. If I remove the parameter however, I get no error (but of course the sorting doesn't work either).

Is it not allowed to pass a parameter this way inside the `f:facet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings inside EL expressions must be expressed inside simple cotes :

```
   <h:commandLink
       value="name"
       actionListener="#{albumListBean.sort('album_name')}">
   </h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Yes, that is invariably true and always has been. I should probably get some sleep :) Thanks!